# Qualifier task and main task for Toloka project

Tags: toloka

Can my qualifier task be SBS and the main task be Curation for my Toloka project? And how are skills related to qualifier tasks?  Can I use new skills created in one project for others?

Answer (score 0):

You can get performers in one project and give them access by skill to any other project. The training pool belongs to only one project but skills can be used for any project within account.